# Trigger Jenkins pipeline from Slack "with parameter" for specific branch

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have created a Jenkins pipeline and using Jenkins "Trigger Build Remotely" plugin to trigger the build from Slack.

I am able to successfully build the project when I don't use parameters in the pipeline. The specific requirement is that I want to trigger is for dynamic branch name

For ex. `/build branch=dev` or `/build branch=master`

What I have done so far:

**Step1:** http://JenkinsURL:8080/buildWithParametersjob=JOB_NAME&token=MYTOKEN&branch=master

**Step 2:** Create a SLACK command in SLACK and added above URL

**Step 3:** Used "**this project is parametrized**" and added a **string value** as **branch** and **default value** as master

**Step 4:** in branch specifier, I updated $branch.

**Step 5:** Not working in slack when I run `/build branch=master`

Comment: does someone has any idea about this ?